# is "for" and "to" the same?

Tags: prepositions

can I use "to" instead of "for" in the sentence

> it's important **for** me to study hard

if I said

> it's important **to** me to study hard

will the sentence be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are gramatically correct, but they have different meanings.

> it's important for me to study hard

This means that what's important is that the speaker should study hard. This is stated as a simple fact.

> it's important to me to study hard

This means that it's the speaker's judgement that studying hard is important. It might be somebody else who is studying --- this would need to be determined from context. But it's not expressed as an incontrovertible fact, it's showing that the speaker knows this is their own judgement that others might disagree with.

Comment: I would say that the first sentence could have either reading. Consider a slight rephrasing: *For me, it's important to study hard.*